# Tomcat 10.1 Server not changing X-Frame options

Tags: tomcat10

Our application uses a Tomcat web service to build partial views and insert them into a third-party web program

However, as of a major codebase upgrade from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 10.1, the display is getting blocked by the X-Frame options, which are always listed as `DENY`

I updated the Tomcat `web.xml` to add the `httpHeaderSecurity`

Other SO questions said this was the fix, but the X-Frame-Options header didn't change, so I think I'm missing something

Currently our filter reads as such:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
        <param-value>{Main web application URI}</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xssProtectionEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
    
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Is this the correct spelling ? 
<dispatcher>REQEUST</dispatcher>

Comment: @easleyfixed I may be stupid. Let me fix that typo and see if it works. EDIT: That didn't work, still having the same issue. I'll update the question to remove the typo

Comment: Hopefully its that simple, Godspeed!

Comment: @easleyfixed No luck, sadly. Still has X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY

Comment: I think part of the issue is that : antiClickJackingOption is depreciated since that upgrade.  .  Perhaps changing the the line to this :
    <init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
        <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value> 
    </init-param>

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference. If antiClickJackingOption is deprecated, what's the updated setting to accomplish this?

Comment: Not entirely sure but I think its something to do with contentSecurityPolicy which I think you could use this :     <init-param>
        <param-name>contentSecurityPolicy</param-name>
        <param-value>frame-ancestors 'self';</param-value> 
    </init-param>

Comment: @easleyfixed That made the deployment fail entirely, HttpHeaderSecurityFilter doesn't have that property at all

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, but take a look over here and see if you can set the correct one : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/filters/HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.html